# How to make a micro water dripping pump with little or no electrical input?

Tags: pumps

I would like to make/obtain a micro water dripping pump, as a component of an item I am designing, to irrigate a plant with a water drop every few seconds in a closed loop.

With "micro" I mean few cm³ in size. I imagine this should not be bigger than a walnut.

I insist on a closed loop, meaning the system isn't connected to a water input like water tap or such.

What technology is available? I would prefer a system with no or little electrical input.

Would such pump come ready-made or would I have to make it myself from scratch?

Comment: You don't seem to understand what "closed loop" means.  If the system isn't connected to a water source, then where does it's water come from.  In any case, you are asking for a complete design.

Comment: Aeroponics might be what you're looking for. Just google aeroponics.

Comment: I think this can be achieved without the use of a pump, and 0 electricity, by using a siphon action through a hose, or some other medium such as cotton wadding, paper, rope. I can think of a variety of ways to do this. A fun one might be to use a dehumdifyer, and use the siphon to drain the collection bucket, feeding the plants. Don't like that? how about using a bottle?

Comment: @OlinLathrop obviously any closed loop requires an initial input and given there will be water evaporation, adding water to the system will be necessary once in a while.

Comment: @DianaMichelleMariaSedlak my business is in hydroponic and aeroponics. Aeroponics simply means spraying nutrient water onto roots that otherwise have no contact with water or soil. This system requires high pressure pumps to create a mist. That does not answer my questions here, since I am looking at low pressure mini dripping system.

Comment: @j0h Please do share some of your ideas, I think what you're pointing at is what I'm looking for. It's hard to look up the internet when you don't know what you're looking for. Some details would be welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Despite the terminology differences I believe this is what you are looking for.

http://www.treegator.com/

The ready-made pump is called gravity. The pressure of gravity pushes down on the closed bladder and exerts light pressure to the water that is higher than the pressure outside the pores. This small pressure differential pushes the water in the bladder through the pores at a slow rate to provide drip irrigation over an extended period.

This meets all of your requirements listed.

Comment: haha, excellent, a bowel with a tiny hole filled with water? why not :)

Comment: A cotton shoelace via capillary action works too.

Answer (score 1):

I would initially assume that by "closed loop" you mean like in a [Terrarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrarium). The water travels via evaporation and condensation and the energy input is the light that heats the plant and the walls of the container.

If the environment is not closed off in this fashion you will have to produce water by condensing it from the air (like rain). Otherwise any container will eventually run out. This could be done with thermometric modules but would use a lot of power.

If you meant "closed loop" in terms of pumping from a reservoir for a limited period of time; there are lots of small pumps available. All of them require a small amount of electricity.

Here are some I found in a quick search:

[Peristaltic Pump](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1150)

[Solar Pump](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Brand-New-Solar-Power-Fountain-Pool-Water-Pump-Garden-Plants-Watering-Kit-Solar-Powered-Pump-with/32457721287.html)

[12v Submersible](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/U119-Free-Shipping-1-2A-DC-12V-Micro-Submersible-Motor-Water-Pump-14L-Min-840L-H/32440657187.html)

[12v Gear Pump](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Shippiing-5PCS-New-Mini-Micro-Water-Priming-Gear-Pump-DC-1-5V-12V-RS-360SH/32252758490.html)

[Diaphram Pump](http://www.ebay.com/itm/High-Quality-Miniature-liquid-water-pump-100-150ml-min-24V-3W-24VDC-3Watt-A-/201475966744)

[6v Centrifugal Pump](http://www.ebay.com/itm/HP104-Miniature-Inline-Only-Centrifugal-Micro-Water-Pump-6-VDC-1-5-Watt-5-GP-/231587767607)

Answer (score 0):

Design a simple heron fountain with a tiny reducer nozzle at the fountain end.
In theory, it will empty the volume of the primed tank out of the fountain nozzle which then flows back into the holding tank.e.g I've seen a functioning 20gal bottle system on YT.
Optionally, adding a USB 3v-6v DC micro water pump or a DIY PVC hand pump, to pump the water from the primary holding tank up to the priming tank again to create a perpetual cycle. Obviously, one would need to add water eventually.